# Neatly modifying a member of an inner dictionary

Tags: tcl

I'm looking for a way to append a string to an existing member of an inner dictionary (Tcl8.5)

- Using `dict append` is no good - enables only 1 level of recursion.
- I've come up with combination of `dict set` and `dict get`, but it's pretty ugly.
- At last I thought that `dict with` will help, but it can be disastrous if one of the keys has the same name as the name of the dictionary.

.

```
dict set cfg animals mammal cat1 meyaO1
dict set cfg animals mammal cat2 meyaO2
dict set cfg animals mammal cfg bar
# Method 1 (Ugly)
dict set cfg animals mammal cat1 "[dict get $cfg animals mammal cat1]hihi"
puts [dict get $cfg animals mammal cat1]

# Method 2 (Risky)
proc foo {cfg} {
    proc dict_append {cfgName} {
        upvar $cfgName cfg
        dict with cfg animals mammal {
            append cat1 "hihi"
        }
        return $cfg
    }
    puts [dict_append cfg]
}
foo $cfg
```

The above code outputs:

```
meyaO1hihi
missing value to go with key
    while executing
"dict with cfg animals mammal {
                        append cat1 "hihi"
                }"
    (procedure "dict_append" line 3)
    invoked from within
"dict_append cfg"
    (procedure "foo" line 9)
    invoked from within
"foo $cfg"
    (file "basics.tcl" line 20)
```

Do you know of a neat way which is also safe?

---

**Edit #1, 27 Feb 2014 09:15 UTC:**
*Responding to @Donal Fellows answer:*

What do you mean by *"You can't do ... particular format)"*?
I think that I can choose whether the key will be formatted or structured... Here's an example:

```
puts {Structured key:}
dict set cfg animals mammal cat1 meyaO1
dict set cfg animals mammal cat2 meyaO2
dict set cfg animals mammal cfg bar
puts $cfg
unset cfg
puts {Formatted key (NOT structured):}
dict set cfg "animals mammal cat1" meyaO1
dict set cfg "animals mammal cat2" meyaO2
dict set cfg "animals mammal cfg" bar
puts $cfg
```

The above code outputs:

```
Structured key:
animals {mammal {cat1 meyaO1 cat2 meyaO2 cfg bar}}
Formatted key (NOT structured):
{animals mammal cat1} meyaO1 {animals mammal cat2} meyaO2 {animals mammal cfg} bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite deep. You're probably best off going with nested `dict update`s.

```
# Map the value for the 'animals' key as the 'outer' var
dict update cfg animals outer {
    # Map the value for the 'mammal' key as the 'inner' var
    dict update outer mammal inner {
        dict lappend inner cat1 "hihi"
    }
}
```

You can't do something like structured keys like this because dictionaries are designed to allow *arbitrary* strings as keys (and structured keys won't work with that, because there's no way to tell whether `a b c`, or even `a.b.c`, is a structured key or a key in a particular format).

The `dict with` command is intended for use in situations where the keys are more well-known.

Comment: @Dor: Dictionaries allow you to use _any_ value as a key. If you want to use lists and interpret them as such, that's absolutely fine. You probably don't want to use `dict with` when working with such dictionaries. (When I say any value as a key, I mean it. Binary blob? Sure. You might want to avoid using really large keys though; they'll work, but might slow things down a bunch.)